# Arduino: struct pointer as function parameter

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

The code below gives the error:

```
sketch_jul05a:2: error: variable or field 'func' declared void
```

So my question is: how can I pass a pointer to a struct as a function parameter?

Code:

```
typedef struct
{ int a,b;
} Struc;


void func(Struc *p) {  }

void setup() {
  Struc s;
  func(&s);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is, that the Arduino-IDE auto-translates this into C like this:

```
#line 1 "sketch_jul05a.ino"
#include "Arduino.h"
void func(Struc *p);
void setup();
void loop();
#line 1
typedef struct
{ int a,b;
} Struc;


void func(Struc *p) {  }

void setup() {
  Struc s;
  func(&s);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Which means `Struc` is used in the declaration of `func` before `Struc` is known to the C compiler.

Solution: Move the definition of `Struc` into another header file and include this.

Main sketch:

```
#include "datastructures.h"

void func(Struc *p) {  }

void setup() {
  Struc s;
  func(&s);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

and `datastructures.h`:

```
struct Struc
{ int a,b;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above works.  In the meantime I had found the following also to work, without the need for a .h file:

```
typedef struct MyStruc
{ int a,b;
} Struc;

void func(struct MyStruc *p) {  }

void setup() {
  Struc s;
  func(&s);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Be warned: Arduino coding is a little flaky.  Many of the libraries are also a bit flaky!

Answer (score 0):

This next code works for me as in Arduino 1.6.3:

```
typedef struct S
{
    int a;
}S;

void f(S * s, int v);



void f(S * s, int v)
{
    s->a = v;
}

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
    S anObject;
    // I hate global variables

    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    // I hate the "setup()" function

    f(&anObject, 0);
    // I love ADTs

    while (1) // I hate the "loop" mechanism
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prolly old news, but `typedef struct` allows member functions (at least in IDE 1.6.4). Depending on what you want to do, of course, but I can't think of any `func(struct *p)` that couldn't be handled also with `object.func(param pdata)`. Just that something like `p->a = 120;` becomes something like `object.setA(120);`

```
typedef struct {
   byte var1;
   byte var2;

   void setVar1(byte val){
      this->var1=val; 
   }

   byte getVar1(void) {
       return this->var1; 
   }
} wtf;

wtf testW = {127,15};

void initwtf(byte setVal) {
    testW.setVar1(setVal); 
    Serial.print("Here is an objective returned value: ");
    Serial.println(testW.getVar1());
} 
...
void loop() {
   initwtf(random(0,100));
}
```